# What analysis should be applied to this survey?

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data

I conducted a survey where I presented the participants a advertisement strategy.

They could answer the questions:

- a) What is your general acceptance
- b) Does your acceoptance increease
  when X (for example he can get coupons)
- c) Does your acceptance increase when Y (for example his data is protected well)
- ...
- g) Does your acceptance increase when...

For each question they could answer:

1. I dont agree at all.
2. I mostly dont agree
3. neutrual
4. I mostly agree
5. I totally agree

Is this an interval or an ordinal scala?

So (a) is the dependent variable and I want to test what degree of influence the criteria (b) to (g) have on the dependent variable (a) which is the general acceptance.

I tried an ordinal regression on SPSS but in my oppinion that does not make sense since I get an estimate for each criterion for all answers. 
For example for (b) I get 5 values, one for each of the answers 1) - 5) in the parameters estimation table.

But I want to value the influence of each independent variable at all. I think I am on the wrong path. What analysis can you recommend?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a bit confused. Conscerning the site http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/ the ordinal logistics regression (= ordinal regression) is totally the right one.

Comment: You can see a lightly modified table at http://picpaste.de/too_big_table.png. Can you explain why the table of "Parameters estimation" has so many values? Why it has f rows for each predictor? I want to determine the power of each predictor as a whole.